# Nodejs Web Role Doesn't Run on Azure Local Compute Emulator

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-compute-emulator

I have an azure web role that i created by following the steps laid out verbatim at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/.

However, when i do the `Start-AzureEmulator -L` i never get to an actual site-- i always get the chrome error "Web page not available."

The compute log looks like so:

```
[fabric] Role Instance: deployment17(1798).Widget.Widget.Node.Web.0
[fabric] Role state Busy
[fabric] Role state Destroyed
[fabric] Role state Busy
[fabric] Role state Suspended
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my Azure Node.js tools with the version found here (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=254279&clcid=0x409) and suddenly it worked!